# How can I get the value of a grouping variable in a custom plyr function?

Tags: r, plyr

Say I have,

```
data.frame(foo=c(1,1,2,2), bar=c(1,2,3,4))
```

That is:

```
foo bar
  1   1
  1   2
  2   3
  2   4
```

I can run:

```
ddply(data, .(foo), function(df) {
   print(df$bar) # => [1] 1 2
                 # => [1] 3 4
   print(foo)    # Error: object 'foo' not found
})
```

But I also know that `foo` is always `1` and `2` inside the function. How can I get this variable `foo`, without resorting to `foo = unique(df$foo)`?

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a good question, I don't know if this possible in `plyr`, but in `data.table` you have a special method for this called `.BY`

For example

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .BY[1], foo]
#    foo foo
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   2
```

Or

```
setDT(data)[, print(.BY[1]), foo]
# $foo
# [1] 1
# 
# $foo
# [1] 2
```

Or

```
setDT(data)[, c(.BY[1], bar), foo]
#    foo foo    
# 1:   1   1 1 2
# 2:   2   2 3 4
```